# drag and drop scr image to another scr image

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How do I drag and drop IMAGE 1 to IMAGE 2**

**HTML**

**IMAGE 1**

```
<img height="42" width="42" src="//swnaws.com/widget/v2/upload/x_141.png">
```

**IMAGE 2**

```
<span class="holder" style="background-image: url(&quot;//swnaws.com/wi/a_37.png&quot;);"></span>
```

**I tried this**

```
$("img[src*='x_141.png']").draggable.addClass("holder");
```

Comment: explain it better. what do you want to do exactly? what did you tried so far? update your post please.

Comment: So you want to take an `<img>`'s src and make it the `background-image` of a `<span>`?

Comment: @yuriy636 I am want to drag and drop image 1 to class holder

Comment: @kosmos  I am want to drag and drop image 1 to class holder

Comment: what did you try so far? show us something to work on

Comment: @kosmos `$("img[src*='x_141.png']").draggable.addClass("holder");`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you tried so far has no sense (you need more research), so you are too far away from your goal. But i'll guide you by a simple example and links to the documentation needed.

First, you need jQuery and jQuery UI (this last one has the draggable and droppable methods). You can find latest versions at [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui).

Once you have these requirements, see this easy example:

```
$(function(){

    // make the image draggable, use a clone if you want to maintain the original image
    $('img').draggable({ helper: 'clone' });

    // set up and control the droppable
    $('.holder').droppable({
        accept: 'img',
        drop: function(event, ui){ /* on drop, retrieve the image src and set it to the target's bg */
            var img_src = $(ui.helper).attr('src');
            $('.holder').css('background', 'red url(' + img_src + ') no-repeat center center');
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the live example, so you can begin from there: https://jsfiddle.net/re1xwsm3/.

Also, read calmly both [jQuery UI Draggable Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable) and [jQuery UI Droppable Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable) to understand correctly how it works.